# Special case of producer/consumer

Tags: ruby, multithreading, algorithm, design-patterns

I'm trying to synchronize a special kind of producer/consumer problem.
This is the problem:

I have 2 Queues `link_queue, page_queue`.

Thread `class ProducePages_RequireLinks` (call it `class A`), as the name says, consumes items from the `link_queue`and puts an arbitrary amount (>=1) of pages from each link into `page_queue`.

Contrary, the main thread `class ProduceLinks_RequirePages` (call it `class B`) consumes pages from the `page_queue`and enqueues an arbitrary amount (>=0) of links into `link_queue`.

Now it is possible that `class B` generates links faster than `class A` generates pages.
On the other hand, the reverse is also possible.

***How do I properly synchronize those threads in Ruby 1.9.2?***

I tried to use monitors in both but at some point i end up with deadlocks.

(If i failed to be precise, tell me via comments and I post some example classes)

---

**EDIT:**
A picture of what is going on:

[image]

Examples

`link_queue` is initialized with 1 item
`page_queue` is initialized with 0 items

We have 4 threads of `class A` and 1 thread of `class B`. Each line will be 1 timestep.

---

Threads A.1 grabs 1 link (linkQ=0) outputs 1 page (pageQ=1)

Thread B grabs 1 page (pageQ=0) outputs 400 links (linkQ=400)

Thread A.3 grabs 1 link (linkQ=399) outputs 1 page (pageQ=1)

Thread A.2 grabs 1 link (linkQ=398) outputs 1 page (pageQ=2)

Thread B grabs 1 page (pageQ=1) outputs 100 links (linkQ=498)

Thread A.1 grabs 1 link (linkQ=497) outputs 1 page (pageQ=2)

Thread A.4 grabs 1 link (linkQ=496) outputs 1 page (pageQ=3)

Thread B notices that linkQ is too large and waits until linkQ<16

. . . Threads A.* continue work . . . afterwards (linkQ=15) and (pageQ=484)

And now we have the opposite problem.
Now Threads A have to wait until pageQ drops below a certain threshold.
Otherwise we will run out of memory at some point.

cheers

Comment: Are the queues of a fixed size?  If so, this problem might not be solvable at all.

Comment: well, they are "fixed" in terms of available memory. so yes i guess they are. My approach was to limit the number of items and let each thread wait until the other processed enough data. And vice versa. Its a chicken and egg problem. Circular waiting.

Comment: To confirm - you are manually bounding the total number of elements?  If so, that's your problem right there (I can provide a specific example if you'd like)

Comment: Well yeah that was my approach which didnt work out so far. I tried to throttle down thread B if i see that A cant process B's output fast enough and vice versa.

Comment: Then you must use unbounded queues. I would make this an answer, except I don't know what Ruby library (if any) provides them.

Comment: What happens if a thread tries producing more items than are allowed?  Does it just wait for the other thread to empty the corresponding queue?  Does it drop it?  Does it try adding elements one at a time until they can all be made to fit?

Comment: I'll make some examples in my question...

Comment: Is there a way to bound how many elements might be produced out of each processed entry in either of the lists?

Comment: yes, each link will produce 1 page. But each page might produce an arbitrary number of links.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you are using Ruby or any other language, *whenever* you have a producer-consumer design like you are describing here, no matter whether the producers and consumers are threads or processes, you must *never* assume that the consumers will be able to "keep up" with the producers. You must *always* use bounded queues. Even using external queues as you mentioned in your comment does not solve the problem in the general case, because while much larger than RAM, external storage is not infinite.

The Ruby standard library has `SizedQueue`, which you get with `require 'thread'`. A `SizedQueue` is a thread-safe queue which is limited in size. If a producer thread tries to push an item onto the queue when it is already full, the producer will block until a consumer pops an item off the queue (making space for the new one). This will give the consumers a chance to "catch up". Likewise, if a consumer thread tries to pop an item off the queue when it is empty, the consumer will block until an item is available.

If overall throughput is limited by the producers, they will tend to get more CPU time (as the consumers block). On the other hand, if the consumers are the bottleneck, they will tend to get more CPU time. This is better than allowing the producers to burn system resources filling your queue with ever-growing numbers of items, while the consumers could be using those resources to work through the backlog.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've said, it seems you have feedback loop problem. So before I start answering synchronization part of the question, I have to ask what is the scope of your problem?

If you are building a web crawler system you've described will try to enumerate every page on the Internet, and no amount of thread synchronization will help you put that in the RAM.

How about loops? page a linking to bages b and c, page b linking to pages a and c, etc? The way you descriped your problem, each iteration will grow queue exponentially. If there is finite number of pages you want to process, how large is it? If you are iterating through some set of pages over and over, should you skip pages on the grounds of being processed recently enough?

To summarize, in order to solve this problem you have to ensure that on average one cycle produces another new cycle, by means of some links producing zero pages instead of one, and pages producing 0 links.

Or alternatively, what are you trying to do? Other approach might be more appropriate.

Comment: Generally oyu are correct, this feedback system is unstable in the sense that memory consumption will go towards infinity due to the fact that on average 1 page generates more than 1 link.

I think there is no way to solve this by thottling one thread to have the other one catch up.

My current solution is using external queues to store the data which works nicely.
Thanks for your help